# Some errors which vanishes in the second execution

Tags: r, package-development

The code `R CMD check` detect some error which is not shown explicitly in the file `00check.log`. I run the suspicious R code via the console of R studio then the following warning messages launched. But I cannot understand what this means or how to overcome. These message vanish when I again execute it.

```
  In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :

     display list redraw incomplete
```

Similarly,

if I execute `devtools::load_all(".")`, then the following warnings occur. The second execution of `devtools::load_all(".")`, the warning vanish. And I think this cause the error in `R CMD check PkgPath`.

```
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  display list redraw incomplete
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name,
```

Ref:
[R-studio server returns error after simple if-else code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789420/r-studio-server-returns-error-after-simple-if-else-code-execution)